# ClickOnce application won't start up under a given profile

Tags: .net-2.0, clickonce, app-startup

This issue has come up three times in our environment. After installing the ClickOnce application, I expected it to startup automatically (as I have it set to do after install completes), but it did not.

I try running the application from the shortcut, and it brings up the "[Launching Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/vbteam/WindowsLiveWriter/LookingforSetupandDeploymentProjectTempl_B21C/image_thumb_8.png)" dialog, but then immediately closes and the application is not started. It's acting as if another instance of the application is currently running (I have it set to only run one instance at a time).

This issue is profile-specific. Installing it on the same machine using a different profile runs just fine, but for whatever reason, no amount of uninstalling, reinstalling, and restarting the computer seems to fix a profile once it runs into this problem.

Our current fix for this is to completely delete the profile and "reload" it.  I'd really like to know what the actually problem is though, being that we've run into it three times now.

Some other information that may be of use:

1. This application was originally deployed using Windows Installer (MSI).  I uninstalled the application from the *Add/Remove Programs* prior to installing the newer ClickOnce version.
2. These users were previously part of local administrators group (while running the MSI version). Their privileges have since been lowered to "standard user".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix those installations by creating a new certificate for the app. It appears this issue had to do with the certificate reaching its expiration date.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any logging at startup that shows exactly what the application is doing, so you can tell where it's crashing?

The user doesn't have Kensington mouse software installed, do they? There is a known conflict there, the symptoms of which are exactly as you report -- the user clicks the shortcut to start the application, it updates, and then does nothing.

Comment: I don't currently have any logging going on in the app outside of basic error logging to the event log.

The user is using a kensington mouse but doesn't appear to have any software installed for it (ie: MouseWorks).  

I am noticing that the application's .exe is coming up in task manager immediately after the "Launching Application" dialog finishes. It then disappears before any forms from the app itself are rendered.  I guess I'll have to add some more detailed tracing (like you suggested) to see exactly when/where it's exiting.

Comment: It might be easier to deinstall his mouse and the drivers for it and see if that makes any difference. Seriously, it's a weird, but real, problem. Not sure if it's the software, the drivers, or both. Here's the thread from the MSDN ClickOnce forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/3ab4fc8f-1212-424f-ac35-ba41be66e1ba/

Good luck!
RobinDotNet

Comment: If you go to the ClckOnce cache and find the [exe] for your application and double-click on it, does it run? Or does it fail? If it fails, then this is a problem with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the profile try this:

Log onto the PC as an admin

```
Delete/rename C:/Documents and Settings/(UserCorpID)/Local Settings/Application Data/Microsoft/Windows/UsrClass.dat file
```